# RTSP RTP-over-TCP H264 streaming

Tags: rtsp

I am working on a RTSP RTP-over-TCP H264 streaming application from a live HW-based encoder.

I am sure , there is somewhere a example code, please any reference, web.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the hardware appliances I have had to deal with (mostly IP cameras) use [Live555](http://www.live555.com/). It is quite straightforward - you set up the needed tracks and then provide NAL units and the framework takes care of all the rest. They have a nice set of [test programs](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/#testProgs) that describe the API - at least I was able to make a RTSP server for a Texas Instruments Pandaboard SoC, and there are lots of info on Live555 on Stackoverflow.